# Homeomorphism between $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $S^1.$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Are $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $S^1$ homeomorphic? If so, is there any way to get an explicit homeomorphism? I am thinking about the map $t \mapsto e^{it}.$ But the problem is that this map fails to be $1$-$1$ at the endpoints $-\pi$ and $\pi.$ Is there any other clever way of doing this?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT.** Does removing a point from each set leave them connected? Is connectedness preserved under homeomorphism?

Any claims you make about each of these questions you should prove!

Comment: Yeah got your point. Actually the problem is that in the book I am following it has been stated that we may identify $S^1$ with the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ as usual. How does that identification work if it's not through a homomorphism?

Comment: They are using the term "identification" loosely.  You can identify points of the circle with points in $[-\pi, \pi]$ as long as $-\pi$ and $\pi$ "do the same thing."

Comment: $S^{1}\simeq [-\pi,\pi]/\sim$ where the tilde is the quotient where we identifies $x\sim y$ iff $x=y$ or $x=\pi, y=-\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove one point to each one of your object. Can you note anything interesting? What is the other basic concept often introduced with compactness?
Edit: By the way, the question is fairly standard, I'm sure you can find the answer with the search function on math.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

There have already been some hints why $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $S^1$ might not be homeomorphic.

However, by identifying the endpoints of $[-\pi,\pi]$, you'll actually obtain $S^1$ (up to homeomorphism).

Identify (glue) the two endpoints $-\pi$ and $\pi$ of your line $[-\pi,\pi]$, from which you'll obtain the quotient space $$[-\pi,\pi]\big/{\sim}$$

And this is in fact homoemorphic to $S^1$. To see this, let $\exp\colon [-\pi,\pi] \to S^1$ be the map $\exp(t) = e^{it}$ and $p\colon [-\pi,\pi]\to [-\pi,\pi]\big/{\sim}$ the canonical projection.

By construction, we have $p(-\pi) = p(\pi) = \overline{\pi}$.

Furthermore, we have $$\exp(-\pi) = e^{i\pi} = e^{i(-\pi)} = \exp(\pi)$$

Thus, we descend to the quotient and $\exp\colon [-\pi,\pi] \to S^1$ induces a map

$$\varphi\colon [-\pi,\pi]\big/{\sim} \to S^1$$

defined via $$\varphi([x]) := f(x)$$  where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class $[x]$ in your quotient space for $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Now $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism since $[-\pi,\pi]$ is compact and $S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff, thus:

$$[-\pi,\pi]\big/{\sim} \cong S^1$$